# Troubleshooting HTTPClient asynchronous POST and reading results

Tags: c#, post, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, webclient

I have a problem post string to form and read. Problem is they get away but need to do so sophisticated and it was very fast. Absolutely perfect multithreaded or asynchronous. Thank you very for your help.
This is my code.

```
private static void AsyncDown()
    {
        const string url = "http://whois.sk-nic.sk/index.jsp";
        const string req = "PREM-0001";
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("text", "PREM-0001")
        };

        FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("http://whois.sk-nic.sk/index.jsp", content).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {

            HttpContent stream = response.Content;
            Task<string> data = stream.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you are asking.  You might try writing your question in your native language, and using Google Translate to convert it to English.

Comment: @nørdic I'm not sure what the actual question or issue is.  Can you clarify for us?  Have you tried fiddler?

Comment: are you asking about how to read the response from these requests? Is the trouble you're having that you're unsure of how to handle the async parts of it? The code you posted seems to indicate that

Comment: Thank you. My problem is that there exists http://whois.sk-nic.sk/index.jsp page where you enter into a textbox after you specify the domain owner identifier "PREM-0001" This is an example and give back to the data relating to him. These data necessary to parse and store in a database within the building. No number will requestov in hundreds of thousands. Advantage website that whois.sk-nic.sk is that it is very fast. and can handle a number of such requestov. No need to get the data from there as fast as possible. It is not possible to send the url parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a rough stab in the dark at what your problem is, I'd guess that you're having trouble reading the response of your call.

When the content is POSTed to the server,

```
HttpResponseMessage response 
    = client.PostAsync("http://whois.sk-nic.sk/index.jsp", content).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {

        HttpContent stream = response.Content;
        Task<string> data = stream.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

It does so asynchronously, so the code will continue execution even though the result is not (most likely) available yet. Checking `response.IsSuccessStatusCode` will thus not give you the behavior you're expecting.

Change your calls to look like this by adding the **await** keyword:

```
HttpResponseMessage response 
    = await client.PostAsync("http://whois.sk-nic.sk/index.jsp", content);
```

Then, change the reading of the stream to use await as well:

```
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

EDIT: got some await objects mixed up and have corrected the code listing.

edit 2: here is the complete LINQPad script that I used to successfully download an HTML page from the given URL.

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("text", "PREM-0001")
};

FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://whois.sk-nic.sk/index.jsp", content);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    //data.Dump(); //uncomment previous if using LINQPad
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But this is error message for HttpResponseMessage if i try add await. Error "Cannot await 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage"

Comment: yep, I forgot that it's the reading of the content you await - see updated code.

Comment: It does not work like that. Do not come to this part. "await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();"

Comment: if it doesn't get to that part, then `response.IsSuccessStatusCode == false`. It could mean a whole range of different thigns

Comment: It is still possible some other method to achieve what I need?

Comment: OK I think I get your problem - you can get it to send, but the POST parameters aren't being sent? I got this when I inspected the request in Fiddler: POST http://whois.sk-nic.sk/index.jsp
200 OK (text/html). POST body was: text=PREM-0001

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the site has changed since last post but now the request parameter name is whois not text. If this was the case a year ago too that's why it didn't work.

Today site responds to get too, i.e. http://whois.sk-nic.sk/index.jsp?whois=PREM-0001

Full code with get:

```
private async Task<string> Get(string code)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var requestUri = String.Format("http://whois.sk-nic.sk/index.jsp?whois={0}", code);

        var data = await client.GetStringAsync(requestUri);

        return data;
    }
}
```

Full code with post:

```
private async Task<string> Post()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var postData = new KeyValuePair<string, string>[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("whois", "PREM-0001"),
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://whois.sk-nic.sk/index.jsp", content);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var message = String.Format("Server returned HTTP error {0}: {1}.", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
            throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
        }

        var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return data;
    }
}
```

Or a parser could be used because I guess extracting the returned values is the final goal:

```
private void HtmlAgilityPack(string code)
{
    var requestUri = String.Format("http://whois.sk-nic.sk/index.jsp?whois={0}", code);

    var request = new HtmlWeb();

    var htmlDocument = request.Load(requestUri);

    var name = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/table[1]/tr[5]/td/table/tr[2]/td[2]").InnerText.Trim();
    var organizations = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/table[1]/tr[5]/td/table/tr[3]/td[2]").InnerText.Trim();
}
```