# HttpClient asynchronous Post C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, httpclient

I have this line of code:

```
HttpResponseMessage aResponse = await aClient.PostAsync(theUri, theContent);
```

However, I have an error that says: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

So I went to search and found this link: [Troubleshooting HTTPClient asynchronous POST and reading results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746090/troubleshooting-httpclient-asynchronous-post-and-reading-results)

I've tried what the answer does, but I still get that error. What should I do? Thanks a million

Comment: To learn about `async-await`, read the articles on [my `async-await`curation](http://curah.microsoft.com/45553/asyncawait-general).

Answer (score 6):

You need to decorate the method containing the `await` call with `async` and wrap it’s return type in `Task<TResult>`. For example, if you were calling it from an `Index()` action of a `Controller` in MVC, you would have to modify:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
    HttpResponseMessage aResponse = await aClient.PostAsync(theUri, theContent);
    //will give you the error you are getting
}
```

..so it becomes:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index() 
{
    HttpResponseMessage aResponse = await aClient.PostAsync(theUri, theContent);
    //no error here
}
```

Have a look at [async (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx) on MSDN.

There's also the case of returning `Task` when no meaningful value is returned and `void`, used primarily to define event handlers, which require that return type.

For all the possible return types of `async` methods, have a look at [Async Return Types (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh524395.aspx) on MSDN.

As an aside, these operations require referencing `System.Threading.Tasks` in your project.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend returning Task (for void cases) as it works best when UI thread is waiting for the process to complete.  For ASP.NET applications it may not work well

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the method containing this line of code is marked async and returns a Task object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx